# Request stalled indefinitely in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, request, sendbeacon, stalled

I use the bellow code in order to send requests when my page changes. When I try it with Firefox browser I have no issues but in Chrome browser the request stay pending indefinitely. Can you guys help on this ?

```
navigator.sendBeacon('my-url/session', new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {
      type: 'application/json'
    }));
    return Promise.resolve({updatedAt: Date.now()});
```

[image: Pending request]

[image: Stalled request]